# In Interstellar, what does the Hindi text displayed for the drone say?

Tags: interstellar, translation

[image]

Notice something in the above screenshot?

The PC's language is Hindi. **Do you have any idea what this means?**

Comment: The alphabet is [Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari). Whether it is Hindi or Marathi or Sanskrit... That said, the largest bit of text is *Saphal lāngani* ... and *saphal* means *successful*. No idea what *lāngani* is. I can also see *radd kare* (meaning *Cancel*) in the faded button, indicating that it is Hindi.

Comment: @muru Whatever _lāngani_ is, it seems to be what the bluish button a bit further down on the right says, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In all probability, I'd guess [somebody messed up](https://translate.google.com/#en/hi/succesful%20login) (note that I'm deliberately misspelling *successful* because that somehow causes Google to translate it correctly, but *login* incorrectly). Also, [the frame just before this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zsnh.jpg) has what I'd wager to be [unauthorized entry](https://translate.google.com/#en/hi/unauthorized%20entry) (again, I'm using *entry* instead of [what I'd think is more natural] *access* because Google).

Comment: Just stumbled upon to this one while watching the movie.\D

Answer (score 18):

I'll try to answer each section one by one.

First we have:

[image: Central dialog box]

The text here is: **सफल लोगनि** which is actually wrong. **सफल** means *successful* and **लोगनि** is a typo of "Login".

The line immediately below it actually do not mean anything; that is, they do not form any sensible words.

Below that, we have a misspelled version of **"सुरक्षा कोड"**. **सुरक्षा** In Hindi is "Security".

So this can be taken as a loose translation of "Security code".

The button below it also spells **लोगनि** which again is a typo of "Login".

And the button on the left is **"रद्द करे"** Which reads "Cancel".

So this is your typical login prompt.

The panel on the right:

[image: Right panel]

Now this is a sort of status table.

Here you can see **"ठीक"** Which is *"OK"* in English.

Then we have **"रखरखाव "** Which is *"maintenance"*, and then we have **"चेतावनी "** Which is *"Warning"*.

So you can say this is some sort of a status for a system.

**Source:** I am a Native Hindi/Marathi speaker from India :P

Comment: A note here for all movie writers: Nobody actually uses this. Even in India, we have prompts and statuses in English :P

Comment: Yes that's the most intriguing thing here. Nowhere we have hindi UI on or computers . But Mr. Nolan gave this movie a 'specific' touch ;-D

Comment: How do you know that Hindi won't grow in digital space in the future?

Comment: @Bat I'd love to see it grow, but I doubt the chances. Even in India we prefer such high level system UIs being built in English, mainly because Hindi is NOT spoken all across India. It is just one of the languages India hosts.

Answer (score 6):

Logni is not a typo here. Let me explain.

In Devnagri script, there is a concept of Typographic Ligatures. Simply speaking that means, under certain cicumstances, a vowel and a consonant character written as say 'ab' will be rendered slightly differently, sometimes in the opposite order.

Here Login (written in Hindi using the Devnagari equivalents of L-G-N-I (that's the spelling)) will be correctly rendered by the display OS (Windows? maybe) as L-G-I-N.

A classic example was pre Jellybean (4.2) Android where Devnagari script (and other similar scripts) could not be rendered correctly due to the same issue. Post 4.2, Android does it right.

Even now, since I am in India, I see image based ads on websites that have the same issue. They have been created in systems without proper Ligature support.

Answer (score 0):

It is Successful Login. Actually, the word login is spelled wrong in Devnagri.